# How to get rid of narrow/thin face?

Tags: muscle-gain

I have 22 years, have a good physical appearance, means not over fat and not skinny.But i have a thin face as compared to my body.How can i get muscles in my face or how can i get rid of this thin face ?

Any suggestions will highly appreciated.

Comment: It does not sound realistic to me to make your face look less skinny with exercise. Pretty much the only facial muscles you could exercise are chewing muscles, but I strongly advise against this because you could severely damage your temporomandibular joints. The shape of the face is mainly determined by the shape of the facial bones and the amount of subcutaneous fat.

Answer (score 1):

Train your masseter muscle by biting against resistance.

There are some products designed to train your jaw.

If your jaw is already too strong it might cause tinnitus, but otherwise training mastication muscls is safe and good for oral posture, especially for growing children because their faces are shaped by muscles.